# Get read, processing and connection time using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeout, httpconnection

I am making a client app using python 2.7 and it needs to connect to a server to do something. For logging, I can only get total time from when the packet is send until the process is read by my client.

Is it possible to get the time to establish the connection, the time that the server process it, and the time my app read the packet?

Comment: you can run your app from a terminal and get the whole execution time in linux as the following:

time python your_file.py

Comment: @WalidMashal What I want is to get time from the process separately, for instance like how much time does it take to reach the server, how much time does the server need to process, and how much time for the client to unpack it. Can I do it with that comment on terminal?

Comment: `import time

start_time = time.time()
#you code here
total_time_spent = (time.time() - start_time))`

you can add multiple of these to the different parts of the code that you want to measure the time for as your code should be placed in place of #you code here

Comment: Well I mean like this, to request to server and get an answer I only do one line of code. If I do the time your way, I will get total time of the 3 process I mentioned above. What I want is to get the time of each process. @WalidMashal

Comment: what i am trying to say is that add your code like this:

`import time 

start_time = time.time() 
#code for process 1 
total_time_spent_for_process1 = (time.time() - start_time))



start_time = time.time() 
#code for process 2 
total_time_spent_for_process_2 = (time.time() - start_time))


start_time = time.time() 
#code for process 3 
total_time_spent_for_process3 = (time.time() - start_time))`

Comment: process_1 has 3 subprocesses: 
1. send the packet to server 
2. the server process it 
3. and the client unpack it. 
Am I right? 

If I count it like that, I will get the total subprocesses time. What I want is to get each of the subprocesses time. @WalidMashal

Comment: there should be at least one line code for each process, wrap that code inside the following lines:

start_time = time.time() 
#code for the process/lines-of-code
total_time_spent_for_p1 = (time.time() - start_time))

Comment: repeat the code for every process and sum up if you need to total it

Comment: Let say like this, the server has a multiplication method. My code in the client like this: server.multiply(a,b). That only one line, am I right? But when I do that, the client do will send the packet to the server, the server will process it, and the response will be unpacked in the client. Isn't it what happen? @WalidMashal

Comment: yes and to compute it's time you will write:

start_time = time.time() 
server.multiply(a,b)
total_time_spent_for_p1 = (time.time() - start_time))

Comment: Yes, and by doing that I will get the total time right? Not the time of each process?

Comment: yeah the time spent while this multiply() executes.....

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the time of each subprocess? That was my question to begin with.